# VBA Automation Error: System Call Failed when passing Dictionary in Function with Application.Run

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint which calls a Macro in an Excel Workbook an passes a dictionary
which the Worbook is supposed to modify. Sometimes when i run the function any access to
properties of the dictionary causes that error inside the macro.

In Powerpoint:

```
Sub PptMacro()

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary 
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

xlApp.Run("ExcelMacro", dict)

dict.Item "key"

End Sub
```

In Excel Workbook:

```
Sub ExcelMacro(ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary)

For I=1 To 10
   Call proc(dict)
Next I

End Sub 

Sub proc(ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary)

If Not dict.Exists("key") Then                     ' <- Error occurs here
 dict.Add key:= "key", item:= ""                   '    always on the 8th
End If                                             '    iteration

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake and how i can fix it?

I have tried changing ByVal to ByRef anywhere I could but it still occurs randomly.

Comment: Your use of new for Scripting.Dictionary is likely the problem.  try changing that line to Dim dict as Scripting.Dictionary and then add 'Set dict = new Scripting.Dictionary'.

Comment: Oh Thank you! Could you explain the why that is the case?

Comment: Its likely a timing issue.  When you embed New in a Dim statement the object is not created at that line.  Rather, object creation occurs at the first use.  Your first use is as a method call parameter so it may be that at the time the excel procedure runs, the scripting dictionary is not been fully instantiated as the excel code will be running in a seperate instance of VBA (that in the excel object thread).  I'd hope others would correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: @freeflow I have changed the code such that it repeats the function call. The error still occurs randomly.

Comment: When I try to compile updated code you have posted ppt stops at 'xlApp.Run("ExcelMacro", dict)' with a error of "Syntax error".  Are you sure you have run this code?

Comment: Should not use parentheses here: `xlApp.Run "ExcelMacro", dict`  You only use parens when you want to capture the return value.